# Make Canvas Act as a Button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I want is for there to be a button, and the background of the button to be a canvas. This is my button code:

```js
//Lets create a simple particle system in HTML5 canvas and JS

//Initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Canvas dimensions
var W = 500; var H = 500;

//Lets create an array of particles
var particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
 //This will add 50 particles to the array with random positions
 particles.push(new create_particle());
}

//Lets create a function which will help us to create multiple particles
function create_particle()
{
 //Random position on the canvas
 this.x = Math.random()*W;
 this.y = Math.random()*H;
 
 //Lets add random velocity to each particle
 this.vx = Math.random()*20-10;
 this.vy = Math.random()*20-10;
 
 //Random colors
 var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
 var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
 var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
 this.color = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", 0.5)";
 
 //Random size
 this.radius = Math.random()*20+20;
}

var x = 100; var y = 100;

//Lets animate the particle
function draw()
{
 //Moving this BG paint code insde draw() will help remove the trail
 //of the particle
 //Lets paint the canvas black
 //But the BG paint shouldn't blend with the previous frame
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
 //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
 
 //Lets blend the particle with the BG
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
 
 //Lets draw particles from the array now
 for(var t = 0; t < particles.length; t++)
 {
  var p = particles[t];
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  //Time for some colors
  var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, 0, p.x, p.y, p.radius);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, p.color);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");
  
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fill();
  
  //Lets use the velocity now
  p.x += p.vx;
  p.y += p.vy;
  
  //To prevent the balls from moving out of the canvas
  if(p.x < -50) p.x = W+50;
  if(p.y < -50) p.y = H+50;
  if(p.x > W+50) p.x = -50;
  if(p.y > H+50) p.y = -50;
 }
}

setInterval(draw, 33);
//I hope that you enjoyed the tutorial :)
```

```html
<button align=center>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      <span id="submit">Submit</span>

  </button>
```

For some reason, the button is huge, and I don't know why, but also, I want my text to be on top of the canvas. How can I do that?

Comment: like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq85vm3/1/) ?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yes! Thank You!

Comment: Also set padding, margin and border to 0.

Comment: You welcome, enjoy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the canvas. You can do so by setting the width and height of the canvas to a fixed value via attributes i.e `<canvas width="50" height="50"></canvas>`. The drawing is bound by the width and height variables which you may like to alter as well. As for the text, it needs to be positioned on top of the canvas using absolute positioning. Alternatively, you could draw text on the canvas directly. Note that you can use a canvas without the button and then register a click event handler on the canvas to simulate a button instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/684vtxm1/

Comment: Can I make the canvas take up the whole space on the button?

Comment: The button does not have a width and height applied to it. Therefore, the button's width and height will match the width and height of the child contents. In this case, it would match the dimensions of the canvas (minus padding) - https://jsfiddle.net/684vtxm1/1/